# Typescript - Default function in interface -> Error (TS) Property or signature expected

Tags: typescript

```
interface interfaceForm {
    controller: string;
    data: object;
    beforeSend: () => {
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    };
    done: () => {};
    fail: () => {};
}
```

In line 5 the error is occurring (TS) Property or signature expected

Comment: Please mark the line where the error occurs with a comment to indicate this.

Comment: The line is document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";

Answer (score 5):

> Default function in interface

Interfaces are a compile time only construct. You cannot have an *implementation* in an interface.

## Suggestion

Consider using an [abstract class](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html).